# SSO Between a Laravel app and a NodeJS API

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, single-sign-on, passport.js

I currently have monolithic app built with Laravel with a stable user base. I'm developing another separate app which is a combination of an API built with NodeJS and a VueJS frontend app (NodeJS API + VueJS).

Now what I want is, I want users to auto sign in when users are visiting the 2nd app, if they're already signed in on the 1st app (Laravel app).

Any possible and practical ways to achieve this ? (The harder part for me is the 2nd app is an API + Frontend app).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tool [keycloak SSO](https://www.keycloak.org/)